# Get data from relationship objects in entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am beginner with EF and Linq, so I would like to know the difference and the advantages to use one or the other approach, for example I can see to get data between two tables that it is possible use something like that:

```
var usr = from cm in ctx.ConsumerName
          join c in ctx.Consumer on cm.ConsumerId equals c.Id
          where cm.ConsumerId == consumerId
          select new { Nombre = cm.FirstName + cm.LastName, Email = c.Email };
```

likewise, something like that is possible:

```
var usr = ctx.ConsumerName.Include(x=>x.Consumer);
```

or something like that as well:

```
var consumer = ctx.Consumer.Find(id);
var vm = new ConsumerViewModel();
Mapper.CreateMap<Consumer, ConsumerViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Consumer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
vm = Mapper.Map<Consumer, ConsumerViewModel>(consumer);
```

Can someone explain me which is the best approach to get data from my data base with MVC and EF??? Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to create and execute query with Entity Framework, such as LINQ, Entity SQL, etc. 
LINQ to Entities is mostly commonly used, I think it's a good way to get data from a database using EF.
You can learn more bout LINQ  here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

From the code examples you provided, I think you're not very clear on what LINQ and Entity Framework is.

```
var usr = from cm in ctx.ConsumerName
          join c in ctx.Consumer on cm.ConsumerId equals c.Id
          where cm.ConsumerId == consumerId
          select new { Nombre = cm.FirstName + cm.LastName, Email = c.Email };
```

**Above is a LINQ query with join operator.**

```
var usr = ctx.ConsumerName.Include(x=>x.Consumer);
```

**Above is Eagerly Loading. Entity Framework supports three ways to load related data, eager loading, lazy loading and explicit loading.**

```
var consumer = ctx.Consumer.Find(id);
var vm = new ConsumerViewModel();
Mapper.CreateMap<Consumer, ConsumerViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Consumer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
vm = Mapper.Map<Consumer, ConsumerViewModel>(consumer);
```

**Above is mapping collection of entities in EF with AutoMapper.**

If you want to learn more about Entity Framework, take look at below link, there are many great articles 
written by experts.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907#ef6